# How do I choose parameters for WINDOW SIZE and POLYNOMIAL ORDER to calculate the detrended cross-correlation coefficient rho?

Tags: time-series, optimization, cross-correlation

In my project I generate synthetic energy demand data using a neural network. I want to check the cross-correlation of those two time-series: the original and the synthetic one. I found, that the detrended cross-correlation coefficient is a good measurement to determine cross-correlations between two non-stationary time series.

I want to calculate the cross-correlation coefficient rho using the R package "SlidingWindows" (in Python) based upon the work of Zebende:

```
rhodcca_SlidingWindows = SlidingWindows.rhodcca_SlidingWindows(y1, y2, w = 98, k = 10,nu=0)
```

The function asks for parameters for WINDOW SIZE (w), AN VALUE INDICATING THE BOUNDARY OF THE DIVISION (N/k) and POLYNOMIAL ORDER (nu) - how do I find the optimal parameters? Is it sort of trial and error like when tuning hyperparameters in machine learning models or is there a precise way how to calculate them?

One idea was to use a training set of 10 years, optimize it using the optuna Python package and test the parameters on the test set of 2 years. Does that make sense?

Comment: What would be optimal for you?

Comment: I guess, optimal parameters would be those that correctly represent the cross-correlation of the two time-series - neither underfit nor overfit them.

Comment: That's good wording but unfortunately little use ,in terms of anybody else suggesting what you should do. FWIW, when I do this I have a scientist persona as well as a statistical persona and go with whatever smooth seems most interesting scientifically, but it's hard to translate that preference to anyone else's problem.   I would not fit anything more complicated than local linear fits. Quite common advice is to present something a little noisier than you trust: people can apply more smoothing mentally but they can't correct over-smoothing mentally, not knowing what was smoothed out.

Comment: In your case there is, I guess, the extra detail that correlation makes sense to the extent that there is a linear relationship locally.